# How many pictures per play should I take in outdoor sports?

Tags: focus, sports

I have recently started photographing outdoor sports, and I want to know when I see a good play happening, should I immediately hold down the rapid-shot button, and take a ton of pictures hoping to get a good one? Or should I set the camera and take a few pictures of the intense moments? Even after he game, I usually only end up deleting the really bad pictures, and keep all of the in-focus pictures thinking that they portray a good action sequence? So, to sum it up, is there a good balance between lots of pictures and a small amount of space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're shooting at 1/500th of a second at 10 fps, you're missing 98% of the possible action.  :)

While I do fire rapidly at key moments, I think you'd be better served waiting for those key moments rather than just mashing the shutter button when you see a good play starting.  Depending on your buffer size, you may be out of room and waiting for the buffer to catch up when the really good action is happening.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to taking photos of sport I find the more the better, sometimes it only takes a player to move a small amount to make a difference to the end image. That said I found that the more often I did it the less images I took as I was able to learn from previous successes and failures. Shoot away!